# How to run test in parallel (per test) using Gradle and JUnit

Tags: gradle, groovy

Can you run tests in a single Test class in parallel (per method)?

I am setting parallel execution with

```
test {
  maxParallelForks = 2
}
```

sample test

```
public class MyTest {
    @org.junit.Test
    public void testOne() {}

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testTwo() {}
}
```

but it works only with multiple classes.

Comment: I don't think Gradle allows this. What's the use-case? I presume you have a test class that has several very long-running test methods. If so, why not split it up into multiple classes possibly with a common abstract super-class?

Comment: @user31601 - that's because I don't own the executed test class, therefore I cannot split it :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no support for this in Gradle, the [finest level of parallelisation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) is at the test class level.